# IOS SDK Ebook app

Tags: iphone, sdk

i want to make a EbookApp . The Book has 400 pages. 
I tried with UIScrollView + UIPageControl , but pagecontrol shows just peak 20 pages.
I heard that it can be done with UILabel and three Views.
How can i realize it?

Comment: You know about rule [2.21](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)? `Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes store. Apps that are simply a book should be submitted to the iBookstore.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't load all the pages at time. You should automatically load only 10, for example.

Assume user opens 1st page. So you have to load 1-10 pages, when user is on 5th page you should load 11-15 pages, when user is on 10th page you have to unload 1-5 pages, etc.

Theoretically, it could be done with three views (pages).

Good luck

Comment: And scroll view. Of course, there could be some interface elements, like buttons or tableview-based list of contents, but basically it is scrollview with imageviews on it.